# How to take output of dir search and modify specified file

Tags: powershell, batch-file, cmd

I'm trying to use this script to assist technicians with renaming files that are found on an end users computer within their %appdata% folder. The script works up until this point, but I can't figure out how to take the output of the DIR search to use it as the current directory so I can modify the destination folder.

Basically, I need to make changes to this folder:
C:\users\bob\appdata\local\apps\2.0\'7'\'7'\time...exe_bfe88f94fc69adaa_0005.0011_none_b883acbb6e8d0075

The two 7's or wildcards are always different folder directory names, so that's why I can't use a static path to make changes to these folders. Anyways, here is the script so far, it works just fine in locating the folder I need, but I cannot seem to use the output to specify it as the target so I can make changes to it. Thank you for your help.

```
cd %appdata% 
cd ..
cd local\apps\2.0
dir "time...exe_bfe88f94fc69adaa_0005.0011_none_39f58db4ac6311ec" /ad /s
```

I've tried using the pipeline argument (|) and the '&' and then using a rename command or a removedir, but it cannot find the file specified.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: have you tried running `where /?` in a CMD console window? you need to give it a file pattern, but that otta be fairly direct. [*grin*]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a [batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file) which is a little more direct than just recursing the entire tree. It only steps over the two 'unknown' directory names, *(`%%~nxG\%%~nxH`)*, and checks there for the named directory, *(which you should edit as needed on line `3`)*:

```batch-file
@Echo Off & SetLocal EnableExtensions

Set "DirName=time...exe_bfe88f94fc69adaa_0005.0011_none_39f58db4ac6311ec"
Set "BaseDir=%LocalAppData%\apps\2.0"

Set "AppPath="
For /D %%G In ("%BaseDir%\*")Do For /D %%H In ("%%G\*")Do For %%I In (
    "%%H\%DirName%")Do If "%%~aI" GEq "d" Set "AppPath=%%~I"
If Not Defined AppPath Echo %DirName% Not Found & Pause & Exit /B 1

Echo %%AppPath%% = %AppPath% & Pause
```

Nothing else should be modified except for the last line which I added just to provide some output, *(you/your technicians would use `"%AppPath%"` to reference the target directory from that point forward)*.

If you were looking for something in [powershell](/questions/tagged/powershell), then perhaps this will push you in the right direction:

```
$DirName = "time...exe_bfe88f94fc69adaa_0005.0011_none_39f58db4ac6311ec"
$AppPath = (RvPa "$Env:LocalAppData\apps\2.0\*\*\$DirName").Path
$AppPath
```

Once again the last line is just to provide output and show you the variable you'll need to reference your target directory, and the first line will need editing as needed.

Comment: Thank you! Works like a charm. Marked as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

This code uses a FOR loop to find directory names that match. There is an ECHO inside the loop since I do not know if multiple directories could be found.

```
@ECHO OFF
CD "%APPDATA%\.."
FOR /F "delims=" %%A IN ('DIR /S /B /A:D "time...exe_bfe88f94fc69adaa_0005.0011_none_39f58db4ac6311ec"') DO (
    ECHO Found directory "%%~A"
    SET THEDIR=%%~A
)

DIR "%THEDIR%"
REN "%THEDIR%\file1.txt" "file2.txt"
```

Comment: Hi there, thank you for your efforts. I have tried putting this script into both powershell and cmd/batch file and neither have worked: https://imgur.com/a/d0p563r

Comment: This is not a PowerShell script. I have made some changes. Please try this one in a cmd shell.

Comment: Thank you again for your efforts.

Comment: I see you have selected Compo's answer. Did this revised version of this one work?